# Android Studio erro imageview com foto

Tags: android, imageview

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo de celular *Android* no *Android Studio* versão 3.0.1 e estou estando ele no *Sansung Galaxy grand duos* versão 4.2.2, o programa executa normal mas quando coloco o `imageview` o aplicativo nem abre no celular e já da erro e fecha.....

Fiz o seguinte iniciei uma novo *app* contendo apenas o `imageview` é continua o erro, o estranho que coloquei o `imageview` apenas como cor e ele abre normal (o *app* so "crasha" somente com foto) já tentei formato como *bitmap 16 bit*, *jpeg*, *png*, *icon* e o erro continua...

O que pode ser isso?

Código abaixo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.delta.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="139dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="139dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/vaidecerto1" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

<sub>**ps**: já tentei imagem com 38KB 640x640 ate 1.7M alta resolução e não deu certo tbm, mínimo requerido dessa aplicação *Android 4.1*</sub>

Comment: Coloque o erro.

Comment: No android studio nem um erro erro aparece, Mas no celular quando executo aparece  my application parou de responder, aperto ok e o aplicativo fecha.

Comment: Na hora que aparece isso no celular, deve aparecer um erro no log do Android Studio. Veja as abas lá embaixo até achar.

Comment: problema resolvido... possei para o formado svg e importei como asset para pasta drawlable e funcionou perfeitamente a aplicação.. muito obrigado pela ajuda